# Correlation between two data frames in Python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, correlation, recommendation-engine

I have a DataFrame with Job Area Profiles which look similar to this:

[image: Job DF]

Now I have some user input, which creates an user DataFrame. This looks like this:

[image: User DF]

Now, I want to determine the correlation between User XYZ's Profile and the profile for Cloud and Data Science.
I've tried this:

```
job_df.corrwith(user_df)
```

But this is getting me NaN.
How do I solve this?

Answer (score 0):

The function is working, but you cannot find the correlation with a dataframe consisting of only one datapoint, since you'll get a divide by zero error.

Then numerator and denominator of the correlation coefficient ([see the equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Correlation#Sample_correlation_coefficient)) include the sum of the difference between datapoints and their mean. When there is one datapoint this is zero.

It therefore returns NaNs, .

If you run the function with the full datasets then you'll be fine.

Comment: Either the problem is that only one datapoint was used (as given in the example) or the question did not attach an example comparable to the problem they were actually facing. In the first case, evidence is not needed that it is meaningless to correlate between one and two point datasets